# How to set default value as empty string for all rows at once in MySQL while creating the table

Tags: mysql, null, default-value

In MySQL, while creating a table, I'like to have empty string `''` as value for all needed columns instead of `'NULL'`.

Is it possible, is it safe and how can I do to do that at once?

I have the following version:

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.45-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

Comment: `CREATE TABLE ... ( ..., column_name VARCHAR(...) DEFAULT '', ...`

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. This is a question that can be answered by consulting the MySQL manual for [CREATE TABLE....](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html). Basic questions about SQL syntax for the various flavours of DBMS out there should be asked over on Stack Overflow. See this [quick search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+create+table+default+value+is%3Aquestion) for results regarding your question. Have a look at [What topics can I ask about here?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information. Enjoy your journey.

Comment: Don't you mean, instead of `NULL`? Also what exactly does "have" "as value for all needed columns" mean? And what has your research about defaults shown that is relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in first step if you want to **create a table** to prevent from `NULL` values and use '' as default you need to add the default attribute to that column as below:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    user_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
);
```

otherwise if you already have a table then need to take this two action:

1. You may update structure of table then run update query for data.
2. You have to update your data and then update the structure of table:

```
/* update table structure */
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY COLUMN user_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
```

and then you can update the current `NULL` values by running update query:

```
/* update table data */
UPDATE users SET user_name = "" WHERE user_name IS NULL
```